# Index an array using another array - gcc 6.3 runtime error

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer

I read a question on SO about some code that caused a runtime error, i.e. seg fault.

I tried to debug the code using ideone.com and got a strange result.

I have stripped down the code to a minimal version to reproduce the strange behavior. Therefore the code doesn't do anything meaningful. The purpose of the code is only to show the strange behavior.

**Code example 1:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[3] = {3, 2, 5};
    int s[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    int r = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        while((a[i] < a[s[r]]) && (r >= 0)) 
        {
            r--;
        }
        printf("initialize s[%d] to %d\n", r+1, i);
        ++r;
        s[r] = i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives runtime error.

See https://ideone.com/IWo6TS#stdin

So I made this minor change to the code.

**Code example 2:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[3] = {3, 2, 5};
    int s[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    int r = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        int t = s[r];                          // These 2 lines 
        while((a[i] < a[t]) && (r >= 0))       //
//        while((a[i] < a[s[r]]) && (r >= 0))  // instead of this line
        {
            r--;
        }
        printf("initialize s[%d] to %d\n", r+1, i);
        ++r;
        s[r] = i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the code runs fine and produces the output:

```
initialize s[0] to 1
initialize s[1] to 2
1
```

See https://ideone.com/qt43DL#stdin

The compiler used is GCC 6.3.

The difference is only:

```
.... a[s[r]] .... in example 1
```

and

```
int t = s[r];     in example 2
.... a[t] ....
```

So the question is why does the first example fail and the second execute fine?

I have looked for UB in the code but could not spot any. Is there UB in the code?

Is this a (known) bug in GCC 6.3?

***UPDATE***

As correctly pointed out by Scott Hunter the two code examples are **not** doing the same.

The first example fails due to UB because the variable `r` changes to -1 inside the body of the `while` and in the next condition check of the `while` it accesses `s[-1]`. So UB for example 1.

Comment: Next time you want to ask about some "minor" change, you should diff both versions beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both versions, `r` changes in the `while` loop; thus, the index of the element of `a` being compared to `a[i]` in the first version changes, but does not in the second.

Comment: And the problem is that `r` becomes -1 in the loop. That explains it.